# Import Model via Ajax Request Laravel - without namespacing the model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to import a model via an Ajax request without namespacing the model.

```
public function dataTypeRender(Request $request)
{
    $input = request()->all();
    $model = $request->input('model'); //this is the model name
    $cols = $request->input('cols');

    $modelTest = $model::all(); //not working
    dd($modelTest);
}
```

Is there a way to do this? I'm trying to then do something with the model data.

Comment: *"Without namespacing the model"* Missed that requirement. Tried with `use App\User;`, but got `Class 'User' not found` error...

Comment: Same, I am sure it is possible just not sure how to implement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to work nicely.

```
$model = 'App\\' . $request('model'); // adjust for the namespace/folder where you put your models

$data = (new $model)->all();

or 

$data = (new $model)->find(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think without namespace it gonna be a little harder, because your model could be any model, but i think this could help you.

```
public function example(Request $request){
        $data = $request->all(); //get All data request
        $namespace = 'App\\'; //set namespace
        $modelWithNameSpace =  $namespace.$data['model']; //concat namespace and model name
        $model = str_replace("'", "", $modelWithNameSpace); //remove quotes (idk if it's the best approach)
        return $model::all(); //return the modell with all 

    }
```

Comment: this doesnt work ive tried varying approaches but without the namespace it doesnt work